# Create group from multiplication table

Tags: group-theory

Suppose I have a multiplication table for a group.
For example,

```
m = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 4, 1}, {3, 4, 1, 2}, {4, 1, 2, 3}}
```

I would like to create a group from this table, i.e.,
end up with the equivalent of

```
group = CyclicGroup[4]
```

As far as I can see, the only tool for creating groups is `PermutationGroup[]`...?
So I would have to compute the permutations from the multiplication table `m`.

Comment: Would you be willing to add another example or two?  The scope of your question is not clear to me.  Does your input always reduce to a simple `CyclicGroup` or do you need something more robust than that?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Cannot add another example right now, but in general I have a (possibly large) mult table for a group, and I would like to get a Mathematica group object out of it. Could be any finite group.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The multiplication table is itself a list of permutations of a representation of the group so you can do

```
In[1]:= m = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 4, 1}, {3, 4, 1, 2}, {4, 1, 2, 3}};

In[2]:= G = PermutationGroup[m];
```

Now you can compute group properties as usual:

```
In[3]:= GroupOrder[G]
Out[3]= 4
```

In this case the permutation representation obtained is exactly the same used by CyclicGroup[4], so you can check that they have the same elements:

```
In[4]:= G == CyclicGroup[4]
Out[4]= True
```

This happens because CyclicGroup[4] has order 4 and is represented with degree 4 as well.

As a counterexample, take DihedralGroup[4]. It is implemented as a permutation representation of degree 4:

```
In[5]:= PermutationMax[DihedralGroup[4]]
Out[5]= 4
```

but has order 8:

```
In[6]:= GroupOrder[DihedralGroup[4]]
Out[6]= 8
```

Now:

```
In[7]:= m = DihedralGroup[4] // GroupMultiplicationTable
Out[7]= {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, {2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5, 8, 7}, {3, 7, 1,5, 4, 8, 2, 6}, {4, 8, 2, 6, 3, 7, 1, 5}, {5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4}, {6, 5, 8, 7, 2, 1, 4, 3}, {7, 3, 5, 1, 8, 4, 6, 2}, {8, 4, 6, 2, 7, 3, 5, 1}}

In[8]:= G = PermutationGroup[m];
```

This gives a permutation representation of degree 8 of the same abstract group. But the groups are different:

```
In[9]:= G == DihedralGroup[4]
Out[9]= False
```

That is, they are different representations of the same abstract group.